# How to count how many words in a .txt file? in C

Tags: c, lexicographic

This is my first time posting a question.
So I am working on a homework program and am a little stuck on a couple of things that I hope someone can chime in and help me with. Here is what I need to do in the program:

- Your program must read in a file containing sentences with punctuation.
- It will parse the sentences into words and punctuation.
- The words will be entered into a dictionary and the punctuation into a list. Case is ignored when adding words to the dictionary. Remember a dictionary is kept in lexicographic order.
- Each entry in the dictionary and list will have a count of the number of times the word or punctuation appears in the original text.
- After reading the text (a line with a first character of $ terminates the text), print out the dictionary and list with the counts.
- Your program will next read a line formatted like this: word1 < word2
- This means replace word1 with word2 in the text

I have been able to enter the file (hw5-input) and print it in lexicographic order and got rid of the capitals, I even have a word count but can't get it to print on separate lines with word count.. I still also need to swap the words and print out the file again but printing with word count is what I really need help with. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PUNCT " \n,\t!:;.-"
#define MAX_STR_LEN 2048

struct listNode 
{
    char *word;
    struct listNode *next;
    int wordCount;
};

struct listNode *newListNode(const char * const);
void insertWord(struct listNode *,const char * const);
void deleteList(struct listNode *);
void printList(struct listNode *);

// Create new struct listNode

struct listNode *newListNode(const char * const s) 
{
    struct listNode *n =
        (struct listNode*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct listNode));
    n->word = (char *)calloc(strlen(s)+1,sizeof(*s));
    strcpy(n->word,s);
    n->next = NULL;
    n->wordCount = 1;
    return n;
}

// Insert words into dictionary in ascending order

void insertWord(struct listNode *head,const char * const s) 
{
    char *i;
    int x = 0;
    for(i = s; *i != '\0'; i++) {
        *i = (char)tolower(*i);
        x++;
    }

    i = i-x;

// Gets rid of duplicate words and counts words

    struct listNode *p = head,
        *q = newListNode(i);

    while ((p->next != NULL) && (strcmp(i,p->next->word) > 0)) 
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    if(p->next != NULL && strcmp(i,p->next->word) == 0)
    {
        p->next->wordCount++;
    } else {
        q->next = p->next;
        p->next = q;
    }
}

// Free all memory allocated for the list

void deleteList(struct listNode *head) 
{
    struct listNode *p = head, *q;
    while (p != NULL) 
    {
        q = p->next;
        free(p->word);
        free(p);
        p = q;
    }
}

// Print the dictionary

void printList(struct listNode *head) 
{
    struct listNode *p = head->next;

    while (p != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%s ",p->word);
        p = p->next;
    }
    puts("");
}

// Enter file and print words in lexicographic order

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char line[MAX_STR_LEN], *s, fileName[MAX_STR_LEN];
    struct listNode *head = newListNode("");

    int i = 0;
    char c;

    FILE *p;

    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
        if((p = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("File not found.");
            return 0;
        }

    while((c = getc(p)) != '$')
    { 
        line[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';
    for(s = strtok(line,PUNCT); s != NULL; s = strtok(NULL,PUNCT)) 
    {
        insertWord(head,s);
    }
    printf("Lexicographical order: ");
    printList(head);
    deleteList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

And the input file (hw5-input) is:

```
Call me Ishmael.  Some years ago--never mind how long precisely--
having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular
to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little
and see the watery part of the world.  It is a way I have
of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation.
Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth;
whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul; whenever I
find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses,
and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet;
and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me,
that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from
deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically knocking
people's hats off--then, I account it high time to get to sea
as soon as I can.  This is my substitute for pistol and ball.
With a philosophical flourish Cato throws himself upon his sword;
I quietly take to the ship.  There is nothing surprising in this.
If they but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time
or other, cherish very nearly the same feelings towards
the ocean with me.
$
substitute < replacement
whale < zebra
myself < oneself
```

I need it to print alphabeticly on next line like this:

```
a - 4
about - 1
account - 1
ago- 2
and - 5
etc..
```

Comment: When googling, the keyword you should be looking for is "tokeniser" or "tokenizer"

Comment: Someone else was doing this a couple days ago, their code might be available.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Are you constrained to the use of C? I probably would do such a task with a bit of shell scripting

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

After further review, it appears you are already doing strtok.  The real question you have is, "What is the best C list implementation for strings?"

Comment: Prof recommended using a sting tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft / Amazon type of question:
I will do a pseudocode for you, `C` implementation:

```
    define a struct like:

    struct node{
       int count;
       char * word;
       struct node *next;
   }Node;

   open the file for read;
   for each line in the file do:
         split the line, in other to have each work separately
         for each work in the line do:
            check if the work already exist in the list
            if not, create a new node
                   node->word = word
                   node->count = 1
            else:
                   node->count += 1

   sort the list by the node->word param
```

The implementation is left was exercise! However, if you can use `map` your life will be simpler!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use my wordcount function so I just edited the print statement under my printList function to:

```
printf("%15s (%2d)\n",p->word, p->wordCount);
```

It then was able to print out all the words in lexicographic order with the word count by them.

```
Enter file name: hw5-input
Lexicographical order:
              a ( 5)
          about ( 2)
        account ( 1)
            ago ( 1)
            all ( 1)
         almost ( 1)
             an ( 1)
            and ( 7)
             as ( 2)
           ball ( 1)
         before ( 1)
       bringing ( 1)
            but ( 1)
           call ( 1)
            can ( 1)
           cato ( 1)
        cherish ( 1)
    circulation ( 1)
         coffin ( 1)
           damp ( 1)
         degree ( 1)
   deliberately ( 1)
        driving ( 1)
        drizzly ( 1)
     especially ( 1)
          every ( 1)
       feelings ( 1)
           find ( 2)
       flourish ( 1)
            for ( 1)
           from ( 1)
        funeral ( 1)
            get ( 2)
           grim ( 1)
        growing ( 1)
           hand ( 1)
           hats ( 1)
           have ( 1)
         having ( 1)
           high ( 1)
        himself ( 1)
            his ( 1)
            how ( 1)
          hypos ( 1)
              i ( 9)
             if ( 1)
             in ( 4)
       interest ( 1)
           into ( 1)
  involuntarily ( 1)
             is ( 4)
        ishmael ( 1)
             it ( 5)
           knew ( 1)
       knocking ( 1)
         little ( 2)
           long ( 1)
             me ( 5)
           meet ( 1)
            men ( 1)
   methodically ( 1)
           mind ( 1)
          money ( 1)
          moral ( 1)
          mouth ( 1)
             my ( 4)
         myself ( 2)
         nearly ( 1)
          never ( 1)
             no ( 1)
        nothing ( 2)
       november ( 1)
          ocean ( 1)
             of ( 4)
            off ( 2)
             on ( 1)
             or ( 2)
          other ( 1)
           part ( 1)
     particular ( 1)
        pausing ( 1)
       people's ( 1)
  philosophical ( 1)
         pistol ( 1)
      precisely ( 1)
        prevent ( 1)
      principle ( 1)
          purse ( 1)
        quietly ( 1)
           rear ( 1)
     regulating ( 1)
       requires ( 1)
           sail ( 1)
           same ( 1)
            sea ( 1)
            see ( 1)
           ship ( 1)
          shore ( 1)
           some ( 2)
           soon ( 1)
           soul ( 1)
         spleen ( 1)
       stepping ( 1)
         street ( 1)
         strong ( 1)
     substitute ( 1)
           such ( 1)
     surprising ( 1)
          sword ( 1)
           take ( 1)
           that ( 1)
            the (10)
          their ( 1)
           then ( 1)
          there ( 1)
           they ( 1)
           this ( 2)
        thought ( 1)
         throws ( 1)
           time ( 2)
             to ( 5)
        towards ( 1)
             up ( 1)
           upon ( 1)
          upper ( 1)
           very ( 1)
     warehouses ( 1)
         watery ( 1)
            way ( 1)
       whenever ( 4)
           with ( 2)
          world ( 1)
          would ( 1)
          years ( 1)
```

Still need to reprint the input file with the words swapped though. Anyone have a solution?